# Can I combine like and equal to get data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this

```
1234500010
1234500020
1234500021
12345600010
12345600011
123456700010
123456700020
123456710010
```

The pattern is 
1-data(varian 3-7 digit number) + 2-data(any 3 digit number) + 3-data (any 2 digit number)

I want to create SQL to get 1-data only. 
For example I want to get data 12345
I want the result only

```
1234500010
1234500020
1234500021
```

If I using "like",

```
select *
FROM data
where ID like '12345%' `
```

I will get all the data with `12345`, `123456` and `1234567`

If I using equal, I will only get one specific data.

Can I combine like and equal together to get result like what I want?

select * FROM data where data = '12345 + any 2-data(3 digit) + any 3-data(2 digit)'

Anyone can help?

Addition : Sorry if I didn't mention the data type and make some miss communication. The data type is in char. @Gordon answers and the others not wrong. It works for number and varchar. but not works for char type. Here I post some pic for char data type. Oracle specification for char data type is a fixed lenght. So if I input less than lenght the remain of it will be change into a space. 
[image: all data] 
[image: result sql]

Thank you very much. Hope someone can help for this

Comment: Is there any reason your 2-data and 3-data could not be combined into a single specification for a five-digit number?

Comment: what's the datatype of id? Is it `char` or  has trailing spaces?

Comment: Yes the data type is in char

Comment: @BobJarvis yes. some specification determine to separate it. Even total is 5 digit but I can not combine 2-data and 3-data into single data

Comment: @ivanprakasa - I don't understand. Are you saying that there may be other characters between 1-data, 2-data, and 3-data? In which case the string "12345abc67defgh890" would be acceptable?

Comment: No. Already fixed : 1-data(varian 3-7 digit number) +2-data(3digit)+3-data(2digit).
The varian of another character (alphabet) can be possible on 1-data.
So it can be A123400101, B123400101, AB1234500101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your datatype is `CHAR`, Gordon's answer is not working for you. `CHAR` adds trailing spaces for the strings less than maximum limit. You could use `TRIM` to fix this as shown. But, you should preferably **store number**s in the `NUMBER` type and **not** `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2`, which will create other problems sooner or later.

```
select *
from data
where trim(ID) like '12345_____';
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaushik Nayak for analyze problem in other side and help to find out why Gordon's answer not work for me. Thanks for it. I really appreciate. And for your solution also. It was worked. I got the result like what I want. Thank you very much. For your suggestion thank you very much. Actually its combination alphabet and number. So it used char data type. My sample all in number to make it easy to understand, but I was make a mistake. It made miss communication and confusing. I apologize for it. Thanks for all who help answer.

Comment: Little bit out of topic. There is any smart way to wrote _ ? Currently I wrote manually 5 times _ (_____) Can I declare variable and call it 5 times? Example var underbar = '_' and select become select * from data where trim(ID) like '12345' + 5*underbar.  Can I wrote sql similar like that?

Comment: @ivanprakasa : yes, you could make use of `lpad(:var,5,:var)`  where :var is a bind variable declared to contain a value of  '_', you could do the same with a plsql variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select *
from data
where ID like '12345_____'  -- exactly 5 _
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/NZLHZ43430) demonstrating the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I used 
`select *
from data
where ID like '12345_____'` 

I will also get the data 
12345600010
12345600011
123456700010
123456700020
123456710010

remember that 1st data can be varian between 3-7 digit number. 
I can not use _ for get the data that I want

Comment: I tried this it seems okay. It shows the result you needed.

Comment: @Beginner I don't think so. Have you tried it? I tried on my database and I got all the data include data with ID start with 123456 and 1234567.

Comment: @ivanprakasa . . . The solution works.  I've included a link to rextester.

Comment: @ivanprakasa - you are almost certainly wrong. The solution Gordon posted requires that the ID be **exactly** ten characters. If you got something else, then you didn't use the **exact** query Gordon posted. Did you add your own `%` at the end, perhaps? Or made other changes? Use it **exactly** as posted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. But it not work in mine. I post answer with pic. please check if I made mistake

Comment: Thank you... The answer is not wrong. It will work for data type number or varchar. But seems not on char type.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives you the solution you want,

```
create table data(ID number(15));

insert into data values(1234500010);

insert into data values(1234500020);

insert into data values(1234500021);

insert into data values(12345600010);

insert into data values(12345600011);

insert into data values(123456700010);

insert into data values(123456700020);

insert into data values(123456710010);
```

**select * from data where ID like '12345_____'**

// After 5_ underscore are exactly 5 , any 3 digits from 2-data(3 underscores) and 2 digits from 3-data(2 underscores)

You'll be getting(OUTPUT) :

**ID**

1234500010

1234500020

1234500021

3 rows returned in 0.00 seconds

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answer and create SQL for it. It work for number and varchar, but seems not work for data type char

Answer (score 0):

You really can't combine equality and `LIKE`. But you can use a regular expression to do this kind of searching, with the `REGEXP_LIKE` function:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DATA
  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ID, '^12345[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}');
```

But if I understand correctly, for your 1-data you really want a 3 to 7 digit number:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DATA
  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ID, '^[0-9]{3,7}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}');
```

[Oracle regular expression docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819)

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d64e/30)

Best of luck.